# RTABMAP send generated map via topic

Tags: slam, navigation, rtabmap, rostopic, rtabmap-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Current Setup**

Currently I have a ROS Master and a robot client. The robot client sends all data to the master which is running RTABMAP. The 3d map is put together on the Master.

**Desired Setup**

I want the robot client to generate the maps and stream the compiled data via wifi to the ROS Master. The caveat is that I eventually want multiple robot clients to send their data back to the same master. Do I merely need to shuffle code around in the RTABMAP source?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238676/rtabmap-send-generated-map-via-topic/) by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 396 on 2016-07-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Each robot can send their map to Master through `/rtabmap/mapData` topic. This topic contains the graph and the latest compressed data added to map (at each second). You may have to set `tf_prefix` parameter with a different prefix to have a unique TF tree for each robot. You would also need to start each rtabmap in their own namespace (see `<group>` launch tag).

You could use a [map_assembler](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros#map_assembler) node on the Master to reconstruct the map for each robot. To merge the maps, you would have to implement your own approach if you want to do it **online**. Merging the maps from multiple robots can be done **offline** by processing back-to-back each resulting database (similar to [Multi-Session tutorial](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap/wiki/Multi-session)).

cheers

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2016-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on 2016-07-04**:
Excellent answer. Thank you for your attention to detail, I really appreciate it.